# Breaking changes with MVVMLight 5?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I have a little base view model that I use in order to override `RaisePropertyChanged` and `RaisePropertyChanging`, so I can raise the notifications without passing the name of the properties (and get it automagically).
This is how it's implemented:

```
public class MyBase_ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{   
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected override void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string property = "")
    {
        base.RaisePropertyChanged(property);
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected override void RaisePropertyChanging([CallerMemberName]string property = "")
    {
        base.RaisePropertyChanging(property);
    }
}
```

I've just upgraded from MvvmLight 4.something to 5.0.2, and one of the issues I experience is that it complains about : There is no suitable method for override for .
`RaisePropertyChanging`.

Any suggestions / ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `RaisePropertyChanging` was removed from MVVM 5. Here's a quote from the Laurent (the author):

> I had to remove PropertyChanging support because the PCL framework doesn't support this event. I am trying to see if I have a good alternative for future versions.

If you happen to run into this, you can just remove the overriding method, and it should work. Seems like nothing big will happen.

On a different note, the `RaisePropertyChanging` seems to be used if you're trying to do something with the value before it goes away, and I actually never used it. If you need it, you can go to this thread, where the author suggested he can provide a workaround if needed: [original thread on mvvm codeplex](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7662).